# Workflow changing StartOnCreated via GUI in SPD

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, version-history

A few dumb SPD 2007 workflow issues.

I'm trying to change startOn switches on a workflow config xml file but it causes the workflow to fail with errors when I try to recompile/finish it after manually changeing it.. the workflow was previously compiling and working.  Is there a SPD  GUI/Design way to do this? I don't see it.

Is it possible to delete list item version history with a workflow step? I don't see it.

How do I add 7 days to a list item date field in workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can change when the workflow fires upon opening the workflow in SPD 2007, just click the .xoml file and click back to change the initiation.

In SPD 2007 deleting item versions are not possible.

As far as the 7 days to a list item date in a workflow, you would set a workflow variable from that current item date field, then the next action use "add time to a date" to add 7 days to it.